# Visual Studio WSDL.exe unable to convert ONVIF WSDL files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wsdl, onvif, wsdl2code

I am trying to convert the ONVIF WSDL files from https://www.onvif.org/profiles/specifications/ to C++.

But I keep getting similar errors about certain data types missing. For example, doing the following command:

```
wsdl /language:CPP /protocol:SOAP12 media.wsdl
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to import binding 'MediaBinding' from namespace 'http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl'.
  - Unable to import operation 'GetVideoSources'.
  - The datatype 'http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema:VideoSource' is missing.
```

And if I try doing with a URL like so:

```
wsdl /language:CPP /protocol:SOAP12 https://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: There was an error processing 'https://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl'.
  - There was an error downloading 'https://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl'.
  - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

This is using Visual Studio 2015.

I am not using gSOAP because this may be used commercially.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://github.com/onvif/specs/discussions/249

When using a URL, "http" must be used.

The schema validation errors are known and has to do with the Microsoft XML parser being being 1.0 where ONVIF is using 1.1.